# Entity framework 5 foreign key mapping convention

Tags: code-first, entity-framework-5

I have 2 entities Role and Permission with association one-to-many accordingly.

```
public class Role
{             
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }    
}
```

And created mapping classes for them inherited from `EntityTypeConfiguration` class.

When I run my application EF created database for me and foreign key for these entities above was **Role_Id**.

**How can I change existing or add new convention to get ride of the underscore in foreign key?**

So I want to have **RoleId** as a foreign key for my entities.

I don't want use data annotation attributes and don't want to add extra property to Permission class (`public int RoleId { get; set; }`) in order to use it in mapping like this:

 `HasRequired(x => x.Role).WithMany(y => y.Permissions).HasForeignKey(o => o.RoleId);`

Thanks,
Alexey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity framework currently doesn't support custom global conventions but you can overwrite the name of the key in fluen API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Permission>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Role)
            .WithMany(y => y.Permissions)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("RoleId"));
```